# unrecognized selector sent to instance - mistake in properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know that this question is asked for many times but i am working on it hard and can not find the mistake!

I have made a navigation based application.
To costumize the appereance of the table view cells i used this method in my RootViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

   Verwaltung Information * selectedFormel = [listOfFormularies    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabl.text = selectedFormel.nameFormel;

   return cell;
}
```

The variable "nameFormel" is declared in VerwaltungInformation as NSString with property and synthesize.
But instead I get this  error message:

```
[FormelViewController nameFormel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgument', reason : [FormelViewControlle nameFormel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I need some help! Since days I have been working on it but I can NOT find the error...If somebody need some more details to answer, please leave a comment.

Comment: Did you `@synthesize` the property?

Comment: What is selectedInfo ? does it crash here ?

Comment: Yeah, i used syntesize and also xcode doesn't show any mistakes. And 'selectedInfo" is a mistake. I have tapped a wrong variable. In my code I am also using selectedFormel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `[listOfFormularies objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` returns an `FormelViewController` object, not an object of type `VerwaltungInformation`.

You should check your data (i.e. the listOfFormularies array).